# How do I make my computer ask before shutting down instantly?

Tags: xfce, power-management, alpine-linux

I've just installed Alpine Linux with XFCE and I really like it, though one thing makes it nearly unusable for me. That's the fact that when I press the power button it immediately shuts off with no warning. This is a problem because on the laptop I'm using, the power button doesn't require much force applied to it to be activated and is in a position on the laptop that makes it very easy to accidentally press.

Is there a way to make it ask what to do when the button is pressed, akin to Ubuntu? All I could find in the settings manager is the option under `Power Manager -> Buttons -> When button is pressed: Ask`, though this seems not to change the functionality of the power button at all. Am I missing something? Is the that menu in the power options supposed to change it, or is this the indented purpose of the power button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpine Linux seems to be a lightweight distribution, so it might not include an ACPI event handling subsystem by default. Make sure you have the `xfce4-power-manager` package installed and the `upowerd` service it depends on is running.

(Depending on how the split between the settings manager and the ACPI event subsystem was handled in the software packaging, it might be possible that you see the power manager settings even though no power manager is actually installed.)

If the ACPI event handling infrastructure is not in place, the system might be falling back to the firmware defaults on handling the power button press... which might result in an immediate power-down.